# Make a post in several pages using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In brief, I have the following function:

```
$(function() { // on load function, everything inside here will not run until the pagehas had time to load  
    $('.filter').click(function(){ 
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = 
        "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";
        
        var datastring = $('#testform').serialize(); // this will create key/value pairs to send to the phph page like `duration5=5` with a `&` separating each key/value pair 
        $('#display-datastring').html(datastring); // this line is just so you can see the variable being created 
        
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'fetch_pages.php', 
            type: 'post', 
            data: datastring, 
            success: function(res){ 
                $('#results').html(res); 
            } 
        });     
    }); 
});
```

Where the result gets posted to the url fetch_pages.php. In brief, I would like it to be posted at fetch_pages.php and at the following functions/usersearch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try something like this?

```
var urls = ['fetch_pages.php','functions/usersearch.php'];

$.each(urls, function(i,url){ 
    $.ajax(url, 
    { 
        type: 'POST',
        data: datastring,
        success: function (data) { 
            $('#results').html(data); 
        } 
    });
});
```